# how to recover earlier version of an apiray blueprint file

Tags: apiary.io

I was creating the documentation for my project using the `apiray bueprint file`. I made some changes and `accidentally pressed save and publish`. Now i want to `recover the earlier version` of that file. How can i do that ? Is there some way to `revert that commit action` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can revert version, if you have connected your project to github.
As far as I know there is no way to revert it via apiary editor

Comment: Sadly, i havent synced my project to github. The reason being, apiary doest allow us to sync multiple blueprint files with github in case of free version.I think we can sync only one blueprint file.

Comment: That's true. A work around might be to use hercule as build tool before submit it to apiary. https://github.com/jamesramsay/hercule